# BASH save stdout to new file upon execution

Tags: linux, bash, exec, stdout, tee

please bear with me if my terminology or syntax is less than stellar (still learning). I currently have a simple bash script that checks the arguments of the command and outputs files names with matching text. This part of my script works correctly via a grep command and piped to xargs for proper formatting.

When running the script, I run through a simple loop to check if the value is null and then move to running my variable/search if not.

My question is: Is it possible to have this script output via stdout AND also save a new file each time it is run with the user input and date/time? (but not overwrite) EX: report-bob-0729161500.rpt

I saw same other suggestions to use tee with the command, but I was trying to get it to work within the script.  Similarly, another suggestion stated to utilize exec > >(tee -i logfile.txt), but I am unsure how to properly format this to include the date/time and $1 input into new files each time the script is executed.

Any help or suggested resources?

Thank you.

```
    SEARCH=`[search_variable]`                                                                  

    if [ -z "$SEARCH" ]                                                                               
    then                                                                                              
    echo "$1 not found."                                                                              
    else                                                                                              
    echo -e "REPORT LISTING\n\n"                                                                  
    echo "$SEARCH"                                                                                    
    fi
```

EDIT: I did try simply piping the echo statements to the tee command, which does work. However, I am still curious if anyone has other suggestions to accomplish this same task via alternative methods. Thank you.

With echo statements piped to tee:

```
    SEARCH=`[search_variable]`                                                                  
    DATE=`date +"%m%d%y%k%M"`        

    if [ -z "$SEARCH" ]                                                                               
    then                                                                                              
    echo "$1 not found."                                                                              
    else                                                                                              
    echo -e "REPORT LISTING\n\n" | tee tps-list-$1-$DATE.rpt                                                               
    echo "$SEARCH" | tee tps-list-$1-$DATE.rpt                                                                                    
    fi
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it *within* the script, why then not just write to
both standard output and the file (using append where appropriate?).
Maybe a bit more writing, but it gives complete control.

Leon

Comment: Honestly, I am not sure the best way to approach this, thus the reason I included the two suggestions with tee.   I know I want to have it within the script, but redirecting each line seems redundant. I was hoping for some suggestions or resources that could shed some more light on either using tee within the script or some other command that I am unaware of that will create new files (not appending a single log file).